# SAML 2 / spring-security current status?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-saml2

I'm trying to figure out how to build SAML support in our existing application (as a SP). As it stands, it seems the newest approach is to use SAML support at the spring-security-core level (currently version 5.3.1).

However, it its current state I'm having trouble understanding how to get started, I cannot even figure out how to import idp metadata from xml. It seems I have to do the conversion manually to a corresponding RelyingPartyRegistration?

Is the discontinued spring-security-saml extension still the way to go? It appears to have a more complete set of features, and can parse metadata xml (which is one of the first things I'd expect...)

It's quite hard to find information that is relevant at this specific date

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to set up the new spring-security-core way?

Comment: Yes, and indeed support for importing Idp metadata from a URL was not yet implemented when I submitted this question. I can't remember exactly when it was added but it is now available and documented here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-saml2login-relyingpartyregistration

SP metadata generation is also implemented now.

One thing that doesn't seem supported as such is importing static metadata xml. If not available at a URL, I still have to parse it manually (not that much of a big deal).

I guess I should answer my own question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for "configuration by Asserting Party Metadata endpoint" was added in Spring Security 5.4.0:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.0/reference/html5/#servlet-saml2login-relyingpartyregistration